# Hibernate can read the content of hibernate.cfg.xml but still give errors?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know this is a old question,but it really trap me.

I take the advice of get inputsream using classLoader, code like following:

```
 public static Session getSession() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        InputStream xmlInputStream = 
                ResourceUtil.getInputStream(HibernateDBUtil.class, CFG_XML);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(xmlInputStream);
        //just a test I can read the xml file ,print content here
        while(scanner.hasNext()) System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        scanner.close();
        //reget the stream
        xmlInputStream = 
                ResourceUtil.getInputStream(HibernateDBUtil.class, CFG_XML);
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.addInputStream(xmlInputStream).configure();
        // version 4.3 's way to config
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = 
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings
                (cfg.getProperties());  
        StandardServiceRegistryImpl registry = 
                (StandardServiceRegistryImpl) builder.build();  

        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(registry);  
    }
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static final String CFG_XML = "properties/hibernate.cfg.xml";
```

I confirm ResourceUtil.getInputStream is work fine,since I can print the content of hibernate.cfg.xml,but why still give me the error:

**update:**
**full stack trace:**

> INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.0.Final}
>   Jan 10, 2014 11:33:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>
> INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found Jan 10, 2014 11:33:43
>   PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
>
> INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist Jan 10, 2014
>   11:33:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure INFO: HHH000043:
>   Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml Jan 10, 2014 11:33:44 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
>
> INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml Exception
>   in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>   not found at
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)atorg.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2093)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2074)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
>     at
>   cn.edu.gdut.utils.HibernateDBUtil.getSession(HibernateDBUtil.java:49)
>     at
>   cn.edu.gdut.utils.HibernateDBUtil.listBasicElement(HibernateDBUtil.java:25)
>     at cn.edu.gdut.utils.HibernateDBUtil.main(HibernateDBUtil.java:20)

Comment: Please provide full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks,see full stack.I try to make the stack text looks better but failed,hope not upset you.

Comment: It seems that hibernate is unable to find your hibernate.cfg.xml. Try to create a file with CFG_XML as path argument and check where the method getAbsolutePath() will lead to. Maybe you have a wrong root directory?

Comment: Thanks.Sorry for my late reply.In fact,In the code above,I can get the xmlInputstream content(see scanner,I can read it content),it means there is nothing wrong.I use a classloader to load resource within a ResourceUtil class,it working fine with other parts,such as icons and property files.But Hibernate just can not find the xmlInputStream,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it doesn't really matter where the file is in your IDE. All it matter is where the file will be during execution time, in the final bundle.

So, assuming , your `properties/` folder should become the root of the executed bundle.This way, as hibernate.cfg.xml is in `properties/`, then it should be in the root during execution time. Can you try by using

`private static final String CFG_XML = "hibernate.cfg.xml";`

**Updated**

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

below this your code continues. in `hibernate.cfg.xml` I mentioned `<mapping resource="pkg/name/of/mapping/file/file.hbm.xml" />`

Comment: thanks.I try it before,but not work.Maybe, I need to read the official document more carefully for help.

Comment: @xiaowang As per my knowledge `addInputStream()` of `Configuration` class is used to Read mappings from an InputStream and not to read hibernate configuration file. either you have to use `setProperty()` to set different properties of hibernate like `hibernate.dialect` etc or pass cfg file using `SettingsFactory`

Comment: I agree with update.if you want to use `cfg.xml` file then you have to use code mentioned above.otherwise you can use `setProperty()` to set hibernate configuration from code and pass hbm inputStream  using `addInputStream()` to `Configuration`

Comment: thank you,I read [questions/8830357] and read the source code ,understand it .My conclusion is don't mix configuration file  hibernate.cfg.xml and  xxx.hbm.xml mapping file.And we'd better make javadoc work when using Hibernate,or will cause troubles.

Comment: Yes, And its better to use `hibernate.cfg.xml` according to deployment because if you did all the configurations of hibernate through code and after deployment u want to change some settings of hibernate then u have to re-deploy/Hotdeploy the `.class' file...I think its better then editing just xml file..